# How to return arrays from a function in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a function to read some data files and make some pandas data. I have 4 paths I want to read and make dataframes.

```
def read_files(paths:np.array,scalings:np.array):
    names = ['E','I']
    for p,s in zip(paths,scalings):
        df = pd.read_csv(p,engine = 'python', sep ='\s+', names=names)
        energy_ = df['E']
        intensity_ = df['I']
    return energy_, intensity_
```

I want to make 2 arrays which have all of the dfs inside them to use for other functions.
(below) where each energy0 is the df['E'] from the first path in the paths array and so on.

```
energy = [energy_0, energy_1, energy2, energy_3]
intensity = [intensity_0, intensity_1, intensity_2, intensity_3]
```

to use in

```
fig = plotfunction(energy,intensity,etc)
```

How can I get call each specific dataframe so I can make an array with them? Edit: If I want to use the energy and intensity dataframes from the path3 if i use `paths = [path0,path1,path2,path3]`

Comment: I am not sure what `energy_` and `intensity_` are, but you could create a numpy array and assign each of the above variables to an index in the numpy array, and return this

Answer (score 1):

> How to return arrays from a function in python

Here's an example on how to return 2 array from a function:

```py
def function():
    array = [1,2,3]
    array2 = [4,5,6]
    return array, array2

a, a2 = function()
print(a)
print(a2)
```

> How can I get call each specific dataframe

What?

I can only guess you want

```py
def read_files(paths:np.array):
    names = ['E','I']
    energy_ = []                      # create an array here
    intensity_ = []                   # create another array here
    for p,s in zip(paths, scalings):
        df = pd.read_csv(p,engine = 'python', sep ='\s+', names=names)
        energy_.append(df['E'])       # append to that array
        intensity_.append(df['I'])    # append to that other array
    return energy_, intensity_        # return both arrays
```

Note that `scalings` is not defined in the code you have shown us.

Comment: This is not it.  I am making dataframes from some files in a path. Instead of writing read_csv(path1)... read_csv(path2)... etc I want to have a function where I put each the paths into an array ```paths=[path1,path2...]``` and run that through the function. But then I want to be able to access dataframe from each path. How can I return all of them and If i want to use the data from path3, how can get that from the function on its own.